What is the Cholesky decomposition of the sum of a diagonal and a matrix of ones?
What is the Cholesky decomposition $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}^\intercal$ of the sum $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{D}+\mathbf{1}$ of a diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D}$ with only positive elements in the diaginal and a matrix of ones $\mathbf{1}$?

cholesky decomposition exists if an only if the matrix is positive (semi)definite, are you sure you don't miss some hypothesis?

The matrices that I am working with are covariance matrices. They are always p(semi)df.

Difficult with Cholesky in the general case. However if you are looking for only a matrix $A$ such that $$AA^T=D+1_n1_n^T$$ you can write
$$D+1_n1_n^T=D^{1/2}(I+bb^T)D^{1/2}$$ where $b=D^{-1/2}1_n.$ It is easy to find $\alpha>0$ such that
$$(I+\alpha bb^T)^2=I+bb^T,$$ and $A=D^{1/2}(I+\alpha bb^T)$ does the job.

If you realize that the matrix $\mathbf{1}$ of all-ones can be written as an outer product of a vector $\mathbf{j} = [1,1,...1]$ of all-ones with itself, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{1} = \mathbf{j}\mathbf{j}^{T}
\end{equation}
then you are basically asking for the Cholesky decomposition of a rank-1 updated matrix. This seems to be a standard problem. Consider, e.g., the following articles:
M. Seeger (2008): Low Rank Updates for the Cholesky Decomposition
Krause and Igel (2015): A More Efficient Rank-one Covariance Matrix Update forEvolution Strategies
Gill et al. (1974): "Methods for Modifying Matrix Factorizations"
